# Regular expression find/replace in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex, find-and-replace

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has some cells that look like this

```
|A|AA|A|CCCCCC
|A|BB|A|DDDDDD
|A|CC|A|EEEEEE
|A|CC|A|FFFFFF
```

I want to do a find/replace that gives me:

```
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
EEEEEE
FFFFFF
```

Whether that's by removing everything before & including the second |A|, or removing everything between |A| and |A| including |A| itself. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: So you just need the right most text, after the last `|`?  There's a couple ways - a quick one is to go to Data --> Text to Columns, and use `|` as a delimiter. This will then put each section in a column, and you can just delete the left most three.

Comment: Is the right characters are always same 6 (6C, 6D...)

Comment: To expand on Bruce's suggestion, you can use the "Do not import this column (skip)" option in the text to column wizard.